# When click on logout, redirect to new tab and current window should be closed in laravel 5.0.*

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

I'm facing logout and browser back button issue. When user logs out and clicks on browser back button, it shows cached window of user profile.

So I'm trying patch for my problem. The patch should work like this: when user clicks on logout button, it should redirect to new window and the current window should be closed.

How can I achieve this in laravel 5.0.* ?

Is this only possible through jquery ?

here is simple redirect :

```
  return Redirect::route('/');
```

Comment: try using middleware to redirect the user if goes to a part of the site that the user is required to be  logged in

Answer (score 1):

I use this in Laravel 4.2 in the routes.php, and worked in 5.0 too

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    $response->headers->set('Pragma','no-cache');
    $response->headers->set('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
});
```

And now you try to go back after logout and i shoudn't

Comment: installing symphony/translation

Comment: one more question... after controller action complete, window close.. how to do this?

Comment: You want to close the window after logout ?